# Open Google Chrome URLs from terminal

Tags: terminal, chrome

I was trying to open `chrome://version/` from terminal using 
`/opt/google/chrome/chrome chrome://version/` command. While it worked for `/opt/google/chrome/chrome google.com` it just open a new window for the first case. What am I doing wrong or How can I do it?

EDIT 1: I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

EDIT 2: Seems I created a confusion giving the `chrome://version/` URL. I am not trying to check the version of Google Chrome's rather what am I trying to do is open Google Chrome internal URLs, all of them can be listed by typing `chrome://chrome-urls` in Google Chrome. Consider this example, `/opt/google/chrome/chrome chrome://chrome-signin/` suppose to open Google Chromes Sign in page instead it only opens a new window of Google Chrome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which environment ?

Comment: Try `google-chrome --version` or `google-chrome --version | grep -iE "[0-9.]{10,20}"` or `/opt/google/chrome/chrome://version/`

Comment: `/opt/google/chrome/chrome://version/` returns **-bash: /opt/google/chrome/version/: No such file or directory** error. I am not looking for chrome version. I want to run the `chrome://{urls}` from command line.

Comment: question edited :)